# HtmlUnit accessing an element without id or Name

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit

How can I access this element:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save as XML" onclick="some code goes here">
```

More info: I have to access programmatically a web page and simulate clicking on a button on it, which then will generate a xml file which I hope to be able to save on the local machine.
I am trying to do so by using **HtmlUnit** libraries, but all examples I could find use **getElementById()** or **getElementByName()** methods. Unfortunately, this exact element doesn't have a name or Id, so I failed miserably. I supposed then that the thing I have to do is use the **getByXPath()** method but I got completely lost into XPath documentation(this matter is all new to me).
I have been stuck on this for a couple of hours so I really need all the help I can get.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several options for an XPATH to select that `input` element.

Below is one option, which looks throughout the document for an `input` element that has an attribute named **type** with the value "submit" and an attribute named **value** with the value "Save as XML".

```
//input[@type='submit' and @value='Save as XML']
```

If you could provide a little bit more structure, a more specific (and efficient) XPATH could be created. For instance, something like this might work:

```
/html/body//form//input[@type='submit' and @value='Save as XML']
```

You should be able to use the XPATH with code like this:

```
client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3)
client.javaScriptEnabled = false

page = client.getPage(url)

submitButton = page.getByXPath("/html/body//form//input[@type='submit' and @value='Save as XML']")
```

Comment: Thanks Mads, I already figured the answer for myself (with some creepy ugly code :) ) but your solution is better and more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would, in most cases, recommend using XPath, if you don't know anything about it you can try the [getInputByValue(String value)](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlForm.html#getInputByValue%28java.lang.String%29) method. This is an example based on your question:

```
// Fetch the form somehow
HtmlForm form = this.page.getForms().get(0);
// Get the input by its value
System.out.println(form.getInputByValue("Save as XML").asXml());
```