# How to Click Button With out ID name

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using Htmlunit and need to click on a button that doesn't have an ID to reference it. It is a Log In button that I need to click on. After inspecting the button, the information for it is:

```
<button type="submit" class="button-standard button-primary" tabindex="4">
<span class="button-standard-text">Log In</span>
</button>
```

How could I reference this button using Htmlunit?

I have referred to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334155/htmlunit-accessing-an-element-without-id-or-name), but can't seem to get it working:

Comment: Use the class `WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#button-primary"));`?

Comment: Can you provide the form detail in which the above button exist.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have another *Log In* button inside a span, inside a button that happens to perform a different logic (very unlikely), this should do the trick:

```
HtmlElement e = page.getFirstByXPath("//button[span[text()='Log In']]");
System.out.println(e.asXml());
```

Even if you have multiple buttons matching, you can continue filtering using the classes or a more complex XPath string that traverses the whole tree.